# How to add Charges to shipping method in Magento

Tags: magento, payment

I followed the steps in creating a payment method in this tutorial (http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module) everything works fine, but i need an additional functionality.

- additional 6% charge to the total if the payment method is selected.

I also use this module - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/payment-method-charge-4050.html but I need 2 condition. That is why I created new payment method.

- 1st payment method - 6% charge
- 2nd payment method - 2% charge

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely your going to want to just create an observer to do what your are needing:

You'll need to look around for the proper observer event to hook into, however here is an example observer method:

```
public function updateShippingAmount( $observer )
{
   $MyPaymentMethod = Mage::getSingleton('namespace/mypaymentmethod');

   $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
   $payment = $order->getPayment()->getData();

   if( $payment['method'] == $MyPaymentMethod->getCode() )
   {
       $shipping_amount =  $order->getShippingAmount();
       $order->setShippingAmount( $shipping_amount + $MyPaymentMethod->getPostHandlingCost() );
   }
}
```

Taken from this article:

- <strike>http://www.candesprojects.com/magento/add-payment-method-handling-cost/</strike>

More reading on how to create an observer:

- http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have the same requirement and I fixed by implementing event-observer method.
In fact you can add any additional shipping cost to any shipping method for any condition by implementing event called `sales_quote_collect_totals_before`
And the observer model method(dummy code though) looks like:

```
public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /**@var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $someConditions = true; //this can be any condition based on your requirements
        $newHandlingFee = 15;
        $store    = Mage::app()>getStore($quote>getStoreId());
        $carriers = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);
        foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) {
            if($carrierCode == 'fedex'){
                if($someConditions){
                    Mage::log('Handling Fee(Before):' . $store->getConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/handling_fee"), null, 'shipping-price.log');
                    $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/handling_type", 'F'); #F - Fixed, P - Percentage                  
                    $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/handling_fee", $newHandlingFee);

                    ###If you want to set the price instead of handling fee you can simply use as:
                    #$store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/price", $newPrice);

                    Mage::log('Handling Fee(After):' . $store->getConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/handling_fee"), null, 'shipping-price.log');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you notice any side-effects by setting the store config value in this fashion?